# VS Code not using selected python interpreter

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

[image: vscode_setup]What's up fellas. I always seem to have this problem and I've tried various ways of fixing it. Including creating the settings.json file that you can see in the picture attached.

The problem: VS Code isn't using my selected python interpreter (pictured in the bottom left hand corner of photo) which is in venv/bin/python. Even though I can select it as the interpreter in vs code when I do python manage.py runserver for Django it gives me an error due to it using an older version of python that came with my computer. I just tried to use pycharm for the first time because of this and ended up having the same problem. Is it just that the terminal isn't using the right version of Python maybe?
VS Code Version: 1.62.3
Also I am on iOS (M1)

Let me know if I can provide you with any further information, thanks.

```
 [![Image of my vscode set up][1]][1]
 ➜  Akutagawa . venv/bin/activate
(venv) ➜  Akutagawa which python
/usr/bin/python
(venv) ➜  Akutagawa which python
/usr/bin/python
(venv) ➜  Akutagawa cd Djanrest/backend
(venv) ➜  backend git:(main) ✗ which python
/usr/bin/python
(venv) ➜  backend git:(main) ✗ python manage.py runserver
  File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(venv) ➜  backend git:(main) ✗ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
(venv) ➜  backend git:(main) ✗
```

Comment: If you just start a shell outside of VSCode and enable the venv, do you get the correct python then?

Answer (score 0):

On the macOS, you need to take `python3` instead of `python`, In order to distinguish the built-in python2 on macOS.

Comment: that isn't the problem, I get a separate error that there is no django module because that is installed in my virtual environment. I am trying to get it to use my virtual environment's python